# Joomla htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting, joomla1.7

I am using Joomla 1.7 and using joomla's built in htaccess & it was working totally fine, but don't know why it's not working,.. please help me in this... i can't figure out the solution and issue..

Below is my htaccess code...

```
##
# @version      $Id: htaccess.txt 21101 2011-04-07 15:47:33Z dextercowley $
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Currently my URL is coming like:
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=465

but it should come like:
http://example.com/index.php/about-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the .htaccess in place (please confirm the spelling - starts with a dot ) is only half of the equation.

You need to go into 'Site' -> 'global configuration' in the /administrator/ area of your website and activate SEF urls. In particular tell Joomla to use mod_rewrite. If you do this correctly, and the .htaccess is correctly named and in place your urls will NOT contain the /index.php/ portion. example.com/about-us  or perhaps example.com/about-us.html if you specify the .html suffix.

Comment: thanks for reply.. well first I checked admin's password and found that someone/client has changed password, that's why when I was trying to logging in to admin area it was showing me 500 server error, so I changed password and also found that client had deactivated SEF URLs :)... now after making changes its working fine.. Thanks for your Help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You said: Currently my URL is coming like: http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=465

but it should come like: http://example.com/index.php/about-us

So this means: you *type* in the browser the URL:
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=465 or maybe *the links* in your page are looking like this, right?

So... this is not about the rewriterules in the WebServer config: they all seem nice, well written and well documented.

I'm pretty sure this is about your Joomla configuration. You should ask to the [Joomla forum](http://forum.joomla.fr/) so that Joomla **creates** nice-looking URLs. There's absolutely nothing to do with Apache RewriteRules, unless you actually type http://example.com/index.php/about-us and there's a problem with it.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I am using http://example.com/index.php/about-us in URL but its not working, but when I use actual URL i.e., http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=465 it works gud..

Answer (score 0):

1. Login with ftp account
2. Browse to the path /var/www/html
3. Right click the .htaccess file
4. Set file permissions like in the following screenshot:

[image]