# Joomla 2.5: SEF links are not working

Tags: joomla

I migrated a Joomla 2.5 site to another hosting server. The homepage is showing up fine, but when I click on any other secondary pages, I get a 404 error. This only happens when the links are set to SEF. When SEF is turned off, the pages show normally.

Any one have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on the server? Also, try renaming the **htaccess.txt** to **.htaccess**

Comment: Follow Lodder's suggestion and additionally check what PHP version is running on that new server. PHP below 5.3 may have unexpected results with J2.5

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, it was .htaccess. I found a similar issue and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381746/joomla-htaccess-not-working. So I copied and pasted the htaccess from there and replaced my old one. And it worked!

Comment: @WooDzu - Joomla 2.5 runs fine on 5.3 as well as 5.4. That would (almost) never be the issue.